# How to find perimeter of right angle triangle given area and three angles

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[image: Question]

Hello everyone,

I’ve come across a question where I need to find the perimeter of a right angle triangle given its area and three sides (the only angle written in the picture is 40 degrees, but the other must be 50 degrees given that it is a right triangle). I honestly am at a complete loss at how to solve this, I’d appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: If you knew the side lengths, how would you calculate the area? So given the area, what does that tell you about the side lengths? What information can the angle give you about the side lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its a right-angled triangle, follow these 4 steps to get the solution:

**Step-1: Angle is given use the Trigonometric relation of Tangent:**

```
tan(40) = Height/Base ------eq(1)
```

**Step-2: Triangle area formula i.e.**

```
1/2 * Height * Base = 20 ------eq(2)
```

Now you can substitute one unknown variable from eq(1) to the eq(2) or vice-versa to obtain both the Base and Height of the triangle.

**Step-3: Use the Pythagoras theorem**

```
Hypotenus^2 = Height^2 + Base^2
```

**Step-4: Perimeter = Hypotenus + Height + Base**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

In $\triangle ABC,$ with $\angle ACB=90^o$ and $\angle BAC=40^o$: Let $a=BC,\,b=CA,\,c=AB.$ We have $$20 \text { cm}^2=ab/2=(c \cos 40^o)(c\sin 40^o)/2.$$ Therefore $c=\sqrt {\frac {40}{ (\cos 40^o)(\sin 40^o)}}\,$cm.

Knowing $c,$ we have $a=c\cos 40^o$ and $b=c\sin 40^0$.

Comment: If you want to compute $\cos 40^o,$ it's a solution of $8x^3-6x+1=0.$